# ERROR: Failed building wheel for pqcrypto

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install python packages in the `requirements.txt` and get this fatal error.

```js
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pqcrypto
Failed to build pqcrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pqcrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried many solutions in Github and here, but still didn't figure it out.

My python version is 3.7.0 and pip version is 22.0.3

This is my `requriements.txt` file content.

```js
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==21.4.0
Automat==20.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bleach==4.1.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
click==8.0.3
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.8
cycler==0.11.0
Deprecated==1.2.13
docutils==0.18.1
Flask==2.0.2
flask-localtunnel==1.0.1
flask-ngrok==0.0.25
fonttools==4.28.5
future==0.18.2
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.10.0
incremental==21.3.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
ipaddress==1.0.23
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
keyring==23.5.0
kiwisolver==1.3.2
load-bar==0.0.7
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.5.1
netifaces==0.11.0
networkx==2.6.3
ntplib==0.4.0
numpy==1.21.5
numba==0.55.1
p2pnetwork==1.1
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.1.5
Pillow==9.0.0
pkginfo==1.8.2
pluggy==1.0.0
pqcrypto==0.1.3
psutil==5.9.0
py==1.11.0
py-cpuinfo==8.0.0
pyaes==1.6.1
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodome==3.12.0
Pygments==2.11.2
pyp2p==0.8.2
pyparsing==3.0.6
pytest==6.2.5
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
readme-renderer==32.0
redis==4.1.0
requests==2.27.1
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rfc3986==2.0.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
termcolor==1.1.0
toml==0.10.2
tqdm==4.62.3
twine==3.7.1
Twisted==21.7.0
twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.2
typing==3.7.4.3
typing_extensions==4.0.1
urllib3==1.26.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==2.0.2
win-inet-pton==1.1.0
wrapt==1.13.3
zipp==3.7.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

Also changed the `cryptograph` version to `2.8`, but not working. Please share your idea if you know the best solutions. Thanks in advance.

**Note**:
I am using windows 10. And this is the full log.

```js
Collecting argon2-cffi==21.3.0
  Using cached argon2_cffi-21.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
  Using cached argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (30 kB)
Collecting atomicwrites==1.4.0
  Using cached atomicwrites-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting attrs==21.4.0
  Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting Automat==20.2.0
  Using cached Automat-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting bleach==4.1.0
  Using cached bleach-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
Collecting certifi==2021.10.8
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting cffi==1.15.0
  Using cached cffi-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (179 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.10
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting click==8.0.3
  Using cached click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting constantly==15.1.0
  Using cached constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
Collecting cryptography==36.0.1
  Using cached cryptography-36.0.1-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting cycler==0.11.0
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting Deprecated==1.2.13
  Using cached Deprecated-1.2.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting docutils==0.18.1
  Using cached docutils-0.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (570 kB)
Collecting Flask==2.0.2
  Using cached Flask-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting flask-localtunnel==1.0.1
  Using cached flask_localtunnel-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting flask-ngrok==0.0.25
  Using cached flask_ngrok-0.0.25-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
Collecting fonttools==4.28.5
  Using cached fonttools-4.28.5-py3-none-any.whl (890 kB)
Collecting future==0.18.2
  Using cached future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hyperlink==21.0.0
  Using cached hyperlink-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
Collecting idna==3.3
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata==4.10.0
  Using cached importlib_metadata-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting incremental==21.3.0
  Using cached incremental-21.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting iniconfig==1.1.1
  Using cached iniconfig-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting ipaddress==1.0.23
  Using cached ipaddress-1.0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==2.0.1
  Using cached itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting Jinja2==3.0.3
  Using cached Jinja2-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting keyring==23.5.0
  Using cached keyring-23.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver==1.3.2
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.3.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (51 kB)
Collecting load-bar==0.0.7
  Using cached load_bar-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (14 kB)
Collecting matplotlib==3.5.1
  Using cached matplotlib-3.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (7.2 MB)
Collecting netifaces==0.11.0
  Using cached netifaces-0.11.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (16 kB)
Collecting networkx==2.6.3
  Using cached networkx-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
Collecting ntplib==0.4.0
  Using cached ntplib-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.21.5
  Using cached numpy-1.21.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (14.0 MB)
Collecting p2pnetwork==1.1
  Using cached p2pnetwork-1.1-py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting packaging==21.3
  Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting pandas==1.1.5
  Using cached pandas-1.1.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (8.7 MB)
Collecting Pillow==9.0.0
  Using cached Pillow-9.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (3.2 MB)
Collecting pkginfo==1.8.2
  Using cached pkginfo-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting pluggy==1.0.0
  Using cached pluggy-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting pqcrypto==0.1.3
  Using cached pqcrypto-0.1.3.tar.gz (1.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status
=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='
pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/psutil/
Collecting psutil==5.9.0
  Using cached psutil-5.9.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (246 kB)
Collecting py==1.11.0
  Using cached py-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting py-cpuinfo==8.0.0
  Using cached py_cpuinfo-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyaes==1.6.1
  Using cached pyaes-1.6.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycparser==2.21
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome==3.12.0
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.12.0-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting Pygments==2.11.2
  Using cached Pygments-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting pyp2p==0.8.2
  Using cached pyp2p-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==3.0.6
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting pyroute2==0.6.5
  Using cached pyroute2-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyroute2.core==0.6.5
  Using cached pyroute2.core-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyroute2.ethtool==0.6.5
  Using cached pyroute2.ethtool-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyroute2.ipdb==0.6.5
  Using cached pyroute2.ipdb-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyroute2.ipset==0.6.5
  Using cached pyroute2.ipset-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyroute2.ndb==0.6.5
  Using cached pyroute2.ndb-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyroute2.nftables==0.6.5
  Using cached pyroute2.nftables-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyroute2.nslink==0.6.5
  Using cached pyroute2.nslink-0.6.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytest==6.2.5
  Using cached pytest-6.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (280 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.2
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting pytz==2021.3
  Using cached pytz-2021.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
Collecting pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
  Using cached pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting readme-renderer==32.0
  Using cached readme_renderer-32.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting redis==4.1.0
  Using cached redis-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (171 kB)
Collecting requests==2.27.1
  Using cached requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
  Using cached requests_toolbelt-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Collecting rfc3986==2.0.0
  Using cached rfc3986-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting six==1.16.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting soupsieve==2.3.1
  Using cached soupsieve-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting termcolor==1.1.0
  Using cached termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting toml==0.10.2
  Using cached toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting tqdm==4.62.3
  Using cached tqdm-4.62.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting twine==3.7.1
  Using cached twine-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting typing==3.7.4.3
  Using cached typing-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typing_extensions==4.0.1
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.26.7
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting webencodings==0.5.1
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug==2.0.2
  Using cached Werkzeug-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
Collecting win-inet-pton==1.1.0
  Using cached win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.8 kB)
Collecting wrapt==1.13.3
  Using cached wrapt-1.13.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (34 kB)
Collecting zipp==3.7.0
  Using cached zipp-3.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Collecting zope.interface==5.4.0
  Using cached zope.interface-5.4.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (210 kB)
Collecting colorama
  Using cached colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting twisted>=15.4.0
  Using cached Twisted-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\phoenix\appdata\local\prog
rams\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface==5.4.0->-r requireme
nts.txt (line 86)) (60.9.3)
Collecting twisted-iocpsupport<2,>=1.0.2
  Using cached twisted_iocpsupport-1.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (44 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pqcrypto
  Building wheel for pqcrypto (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pqcrypto (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      A setup.py file already exists. Using it.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5_oe60ou\pqcrypto_
319c2d280c2742cd8507402183c76f28\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
          from setuptools import setup
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-p
ackages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-p
ackages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-p
ackages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 262, in build_wheel
          metadata_directory)
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hv2lijm\overlay
\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\api.py", line 68, in build_wheel
          return unicode(WheelBuilder.make_in(poetry, Path(wheel_directory)))
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hv2lijm\overlay
\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\builders\wheel.py", line 78, in make_in
          wb.build()
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hv2lijm\overlay
\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\builders\wheel.py", line 110, in build
          self._build(zip_file)
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hv2lijm\overlay
\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\builders\wheel.py", line 162, in _build
          self._run_build_command(setup)
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hv2lijm\overlay
\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\builders\wheel.py", line 196, in _run_bui
ld_command
          str(self._path / "build"),
        File "C:\Users\Phoenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subpro
cess.py", line 328, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/Users/Phoenix/AppData/Local/P
rograms/Python/Python37/python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Phoenix\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
pip-install-5_oe60ou\\pqcrypto_319c2d280c2742cd8507402183c76f28\\setup.py', 'bui
ld', '-b', 'C:\\Users\\Phoenix\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5_oe60ou\\pqcr
ypto_319c2d280c2742cd8507402183c76f28\\build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit
h pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pqcrypto
Failed to build pqcrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pqcrypto, which is required to install pyproje
ct.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Can you add which operating system you are on as well as a more complete error message from the installation? The line you show only says that an error occured. It is 0% helpful in identifying the problem

Comment: Hi @FlyingTeller, thanks for the reply. Just updated the question. Please help me, I am wasting 3 days as this issue. ;(

Comment: Can you check if you can do `python -c "import setuptools"`, also try to update both pip and setuptools `python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

Comment: I did updated `pip` already and all setup tools. The issue is clearly caused from `pqcrypto` package. I will try to install that package manually, while removing it from `requirements.txt`.